# How Client Side Timeout helps with Server resource exhaustion

Tags: distributed-system, retry-logic, exponential-backoff

I was going through following document published by Amazon regarding "Timeout, Retry and Jitter":
https://d1.awsstatic.com/builderslibrary/pdfs/timeouts-retries-and-backoff-with-jitter.pdf
While reading the document, I found the following text

> When a client is waiting longer than usual for a request to complete,
> it also holds on to the resources it was using for that request for a
> longer time. When a number of requests hold on to resources  for  a
> long  time,  the  server  can  run  out  of  those  resources.  These
> resources  can  include  memory,  threads,  connections,  ephemeral
> ports,  or  anything  else  that  is  limited.  To  avoid  this
> situation, clients settimeouts. Timeouts are the maximum amount of
> time that a client waits for a request to complete.

Would like to understand how timeout on client side could stop processing for that request on the server and free server's resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a typo in the article where the writer may have wanted to refer to `client` instead of `server`. Indeed, the paragraph should build on the first sentence highlighting the `client` holding on resources while waiting for requests.

Still though, a `client` timeout will benefit both `client` and `server` achieving resiliency and preparing for subtle activity changes or spikes.

## Client

Whether written using a low level library or a a high-level abstraction, a `client` request should almost embrace a timeout to reduce downstream dependency.
A client should (and will) be short on resources as mentioned in the article  that it can use.

As an example of these resources (and the most common one) client libraries leverage a pool of connections to avoid expensive connections creation again and again overtime when a client is hitting the same server. When a connection is leased from the pool, then used without a timeout, the client can end up with a connection never returning back to the pool.
Given that any downstream dependency can fail to respond (it is fair to always expect it to fail), a client can end up with an empty pool as all connections have been already borrowed by non-responding requests.

## Server

On the other land, and while it is still out of its control, a `server` can benefit from a cooperative `client` that helps terminating a request (note that the connection would still be open) on its end so the server computation and memory resources are freed up.

Imagine a long running action initiated by a client request. A server short on memory can (given a proper implementation) abort the request in the middle of its execution when receiving an upstream timeout leaving it with computation cycles to spend on housekeeping such as kicking garbage collection which will help it get back to speed.

Comment: Can server determine if client timeout (lets say power outage happened on client side) occurred ?

Comment: I mean can server determine if client connection terminated due to external factors like power outage.

Comment: Without a intermediary service / coordinator in the middle, there should be no mean for the server to know of upstream failure causes nor the failure themselves generally.